# Java inject implementations from multiple modules using TypeLiteral

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, typeliteral

I have an issue with multiple implementations of interface, or rather with injecting them as a List.
This question is a direct follow up for question:

[Java inject implementation using TypeLiteral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36690178/java-inject-implementation-using-typeliteral/43277694#43277694)

so I will refer havilly to those examples and refer to their solutions.

I have an interface:

```
public interface IImplementMe {
     public String getValue();
}
```

and 
I have multiple implementations of the `IImplementMe` interface from different modules of my project binded:

```
register(IImplementMe.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("someName")).to(SomeImplementation.class);
```

Everything zipped into list in module

```
private static class CustomTypeLiteral extends TypeLiteral<List<IImplementMe>> {
}
bind(new CustomTypeLiteral()).toRegistry();
```

And there are two assumptions (that makes this story different from linked question)

1. I do not know too much about implementations of `IImplementMe`, in particular if they are Singletons (I can force it if really needed)
2. They are binded in different modules not managed by me directly (and i don't want to bind those implementations myself)

Similarly, I want to inject a List of all of them in @Singleton class and call them whenever needed.

```
@Singleton
class SomeEndpoint {
    @Inject
    public SomeEndpoint(final List<IImplementMe> implementations){
    ///
    }
}
```

And the **question is**: Is it guaranteed that Guice will pick up all implementations ? I know that they won't be available in constructor(the list will be empty) but after that the list should be refreshed as I understand Guice. I'm most concerned about scenario where implementations are not Singletons and they are not used anywhere else beside my class that injects List(`SomeEndpoint` in the example) (I'm worried that they'll never be initialized so never added to the list).

One additional thought: I'm not using Multibinder(I would like to avoid it if possible since I don't want to force other users to use it aswell, it will be a bit clearer if they could just register @Named implementation of `IImplementMe` it theirs modules).